# Image Spliced into tiles with animation - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, splice

I'm trying to splice an image and then have a transition to next one something like this? Any suggestions on where to start from? Is it possible to splice the images into small tiles and animate them with UIView animations? Here is a [sample](https://vimeo.com/11318617).

EDIT:

```
 '#define DESIRED_WIDTH 40

 '#define DESIRED_HEIGHT 60


 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

  UIImage *bigImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_for_Manager_App.png"];
  CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, DESIRED_WIDTH, DESIRED_HEIGHT);
  int widthCount = (bigImage.size.width / DESIRED_WIDTH);
  int heightCount = (bigImage.size.height / DESIRED_HEIGHT);
  NSLog(@"height width %i %i",heightCount,widthCount);
  for (int i = 0; i <heightCount; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < widthCount; j++) {
        UIImage *piece = [self imageCroppedWithRect:frame];
        UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:piece];
        view.frame = frame;
        [self.view addSubview:view];

        frame.origin.x += frame.size.width;
        NSLog(@"x value %f",frame.origin.x);

       }
    frame.origin.x = 0.0;

    frame.origin.y += frame.size.height;
     NSLog(@"y value %f",frame.origin.y);
   }

//[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:12    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (UIImage *)imageCroppedWithRect:(CGRect)rect
  {
    CGFloat scale = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background_for_Manager_App.png"].scale;
    NSLog(@"scale value%f",scale);
    if (scale > 1.0f) 
    {    // this is for Retina display capability
         rect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x * scale,
                      rect.origin.y * scale,
                      rect.size.width * scale,
                      rect.size.height * scale);

    }

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([UIImage imageNamed:@"background_for_Manager_App.png"].CGImage, rect);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:scale orientation:self.splicedImageView.image.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code for crop (you'd better add this as `UIImage` category):

```
- (UIImage *)imageCroppedWithRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (self.scale > 1.0f) {    // this is for Retina display capability
        rect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x * self.scale,
                          rect.origin.y * self.scale,
                          rect.size.width * self.scale,
                          rect.size.height * self.scale);
    }

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.CGImage, rect);
    UIImage *result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:self.scale orientation:self.imageOrientation];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return result;
}
```

How to use:
You should create a category for `UIImage` with this code. Then load image and slice it inot pieces:

```
UIImage *bigImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"big_image"];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, DESIRED_WIDTH, DESIRED_HEIGHT);
for (int i = 0; i < bigImage.size.height / DESIRED_HEIGHT; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; i < bigImage.size.width / DESIRED_WIDTH; j++) {
        UIImage *piece = [bigImage imageCroppedWithRect:frame];
        UIImageView *view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:piece];
        view.frame = frame;
        [self.view addSubview:view];
        [view release];
        frame.origin.x += frame.size.width;
    }
    frame.origin.x = 0.0;
    frame.origin.y += frame.size.height;
}
```

Just slice your image into pieces then create appropriate amount of `UIImageView` objects and place them in the proper order to your view. And now you could animate them as you wish.

Also note that DESIRED_WIDTH and DESIRED_HEIGHT must divide your image's sides without remainder.

For animation like on the video you should use `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft` option:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{
    // hide your image here
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: So would I call it as UIImageView *splicedImage = [UIImage imageName:[self imageCroppedWithRect:rect] ?

Comment: I assume this function is subclass of UIImage. What would a be good rect value to test with?

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. I just tried the imageCropped method. I understand your suggestion. Appreciate it. The one on the video shows each image view flipping around. So would it be fine to add a UIImageView to each UIView inside the loop? UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft is a characteristics of the UIView. Hope I make sense in my question.

Comment: UIImageView is subclass of UIView so it's not necessary to create a special view for that. You only need to store your image views in some array to easily access them.

Comment: Oh! btw the cropped image looks zoomed? Any idea why? I have added the code i tried in my question. Pls help me check

Comment: Try to disable retina display capability. It's not always necessary :)

Comment: // hide your image here what exactly needs to be written there?

Comment: Can somebody please provide sample app, It is not working on my side.?